# How to set a html as the home page of the app

Tags: ionic4

I used easy java simulation to create a simulation and export it into an HTML file with some reference js and CSS file
How do I edit it to make an ionic app

```
<ion-content>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="assets/css/ejss.css" />
    <script src="assets/js/common_script.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/textresizedetector.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/ejsS.v1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div role="button" id="_topFrame" style="text-align:center"></div>
      <script src="assets/js/Test.js"></script>
  </body>
</ion-content>
```

Use these code on the home page but running it does not display anything